# Login hook on Google Appengine

Tags: python, events, google-app-engine, authentication, hook

Every time a user logs in to the application, I want to perform a certain task, say, record the time of login. So I wanted to know if a hook is fired on login by default? If yes, how can I make my module respond to it.

**Edit** - Assume there are multiple entry points in the application to login.

Comment: Accept an answer please, or let us know if the answers aren't clear enough.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in returning to this one. I dont mind flagging yours as right but my actual question was whether a hook is automatically fired when a user logs in.

Comment: i.e. Even though I follow the DRY principle, I need to make a call to the method inside each of my page handlers which can be avoided if there's a hook being called. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

While there may well be multiple points of entry, it's crucial that your auth/session code conform to the DRY principle.

Once/if you're down to a single code path for logging in, you should be able to find an appropriate place in that code path to do something as simple as this:

```
user.last_login = time
user.num_logins++
user.save()
```

Additionally, you could use a memcache cooldown to make sure this only happens once every, say, 30 minutes:

```
cooldown_memcache_key = "login_cooldown_%s" % user.id
cooldown = memcache.get(cooldown_memcache_key)
if cooldown is None:
    user.last_login = time
    user.num_logins++
    user.save()
    memcache.add(cooldown_key, True, 1800)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python on GAE (so it may be different for Java) but have seen no documentation about such a hook for a user logging in. If you used one of the session management frameworks you'd probably get some indication for that, but otherwise I do this kind of house keeping on my opening page itself which requires login. (What do you want to do about an already logged in user returning to your site a few days later... that is, do you really want to record logins or the start time of a visit/session??)

If I wanted to do this but with multiple landing pages, and without using a session framework, 
I'd use memcache to do a quick check on every page request and then only write to the datastore when a new visit starts.